# how can I modify this to work with 3D arrays?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, function-pointers, variadic-functions

Usually, I have a nxn 2D array, and I pass it to a function using this code:

```
void func(int *x, const int &n){ 

int (*r)[n]=(int (*)[n])x;
// I can use r now with subscript operator as usual, r[i][j] and everything works fine

}
```

And I call it with:

```
int r[n][n];

func(&r[0][0],n)
```

So it allows me to use an array of any size inside the function using the subscript operator r[i][j], without having to manually change the dimension argument everytime I call the funcion. My quetion is, how should I modify it to work in 3D? That code is not friendly and I am not sure about how to change this part:

```
int (*r)[n]=(int (*)[n])x;
```

to work in 3D. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dimension;

```
int (*r)[n][n]=(int (*)[n][n])x;
```